# Connect spark master to spark slave through docker compose

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-compose

I'm using [gettyimages](https://hub.docker.com/r/gettyimages/spark/~/dockerfile/) as the spark master container, while at the same time I've got a spark image that's going to be launching a slave node. Here is my corresponding docker file.

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y locales \
 && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive locales \
 && locale-gen C.UTF-8 \
 && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8 \
 && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
 && locale-gen \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Users with other locales should set this in their derivative image
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y curl unzip \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# JAVA
ARG JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=8
ARG JAVA_UPDATE_VERSION=92
ARG JAVA_BUILD_NUMBER=14
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/jdk1.${JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION}.0_${JAVA_UPDATE_VERSION}

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
RUN curl -sL --retry 3 --insecure \
  --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" \
  "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION}u${JAVA_UPDATE_VERSION}-b${JAVA_BUILD_NUMBER}/server-jre-${JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION}u${JAVA_UPDATE_VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
  | gunzip \
  | tar x -C /usr/ \
  && ln -s $JAVA_HOME /usr/java \
  && rm -rf $JAVA_HOME/man

# HADOOP
ENV HADOOP_VERSION 2.7.2
ENV HADOOP_HOME /usr/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION
ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
ENV PATH $PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
RUN curl -sL --retry 3 \
  "http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  | gunzip \
  | tar -x -C /usr/ \
 && rm -rf $HADOOP_HOME/share/doc \
 && chown -R root:root $HADOOP_HOME

# SPARK
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.0.1
ENV SPARK_PACKAGE spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-without-hadoop
ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}
ENV SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"
ENV PATH $PATH:${SPARK_HOME}/bin
RUN curl -sL --retry 3 \
  "http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/${SPARK_PACKAGE}.tgz" \
  | gunzip \
  | tar x -C /usr/ \
 && mv /usr/$SPARK_PACKAGE $SPARK_HOME \
 && chown -R root:root $SPARK_HOME

WORKDIR $SPARK_HOME 
CMD ["bin/spark-class","org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker", //TODO: Figure out what this should be]
```

I'm wondering how could I get the slave to be able to access the masters host and port if I'm setting this up through docker compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have `docker-compose` something like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  spark-master:
   image: spark-master
   ports:
   - "7077:7077"
   - "8080:8080"
  spark-slave1:
   image: spark-slave
   ports:
   - "8081:8081"
   depends_on:
   - spark-master
```

in the `Dockerfile` for your spark slave you need to define master like:
`./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT`

but using IP address is not very good idea. So you can use hostname from docker-compose (`spark-master` is the hostname and it added to `/etc/hosts`):

```
CMD ["bin/spark-class","org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker", "spark://spark-master:7077"]
```

now you can go to:
`DOCKER_IP:8080` -> and see 1 worker in "Workers"
`DOCKER_IP:8081` -> and see details of worker

In case you want to have more workers you can add another services to `docker-compose`. Following `docker-compose` will create 2 workers - details of 1. worker on port `8081` and second on `8082`.

```
version: '2'
services:
  spark-master:
   image: spark-master
   ports:
   - "7077:7077"
   - "8080:8080"
  spark-slave1:
   image: spark-slave
   ports:
   - "8081:8081"
   depends_on:
   - spark-master
  spark-slave2:
   image: spark-slave
   ports:
   - "8082:8081"
   depends_on:
   - spark-master
```